# Error when starting android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I start up Android Studio, I get this terrifying error message

Start failed:
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of
>   com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform. must not be null
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull
>   parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.
>   must not be null
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.(Platform.java)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
>       ... 16 more

I have already set the environment variable of JDK_HOME with the value as the destination of JDK

I have uninstalled and reinstalled many times, and I have even reset my PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have used an old installer for Android Studio. Probably one which is lesser than version 1.3. This is how I fixed the issue.

1. Disconnect internet
2. Remove .android and .AndroidStudio folders from C:/Users/[User_Dir]/
3. Restart android studio in offline mode.

Everything should be working right now

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing you can do about it just go buy a new pc. Sry man

Comment: No. This is exactly what my friend told me before and I bought a new computer and it fixed everything.

Comment: This is really not helpful in any way.